# Why do we need to use a calc function for a simple operation in CSS?

Tags: css

In the [MDN web docs calc example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc), I see a demo example with `width: calc(10px + 100px)` but I could instead simply use `width: 110px`.

So isn't `calc(10px + 100px)` complicating the code for a simple operation? How does `calc` really help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `calc` is as you said, useless for two values of the same unit type, unless they're used through variables, e.g.:

```css
:root {
    --some-width: 50px;
}

.some-element {
    width: calc(var(--some-width) + 100px);
}
```

Which would compute to 150px if `--some-width` is kept as 50px, however, `--some-width` can be changed to anything else, making the `calc` useful in this example - but useless in the provided example of `calc(10px + 100px)`.

They're useful for combing relative units, such as `em` or `%` with other values (of irrelevant type).

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units for relative length units.

The example of `calc(10px + 100px)` is as you said correctly, introducing more processing without any good reasoning, although not at a large scale.